# Toolbar repetindo

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá, eu estou com um problema, meu toolbar está repetindo toda vez que adiciono um novo registro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como resolvo? 
segue os codigos:

```
public class ListarReportes extends BaseActivity{

Usuario usuario;
RepositorioReporte repositorioReporte;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ReportListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_listar_reportes);

    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.teste);
    }
    //Recupera sessao do usuario
    usuario = (Usuario) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("usuario");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    repositorioReporte = new RepositorioReporte(this);
    List<Reporte> reporte = repositorioReporte.listaQuery(usuario.getId());

    adapter = new ReportListAdapter(reporte);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    />
```

Comment: Tem certeza de que seu toolbar não está dentro do layout do seu registro? Alias, o layout que você postou está estranho, ele começa com um include e termina com CardView. Isso nem compila.

Comment: como assim dentro do meu registro?

Comment: Esse layout que você postou é o `R.layout.recycler_view`?

Comment: nao, aacho que eh um bug do stackoverflow pq eu postei o layout todo e ele dividiu em partes lol

Comment: Tenta editar e coloque os tanto o seu layout da sua activity quanto o do seu recycler view.

Comment: Tenta ver agora @Androiderson

Comment: Consegui!
Graças a seu comentario sobre recycler view, eu percebi que o toolbar é pra ta no xml do recycler e nao no do cardview.

Comment: Exatamente, escrevi na área de resposta pra fecharmos a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme dito nos comentários, o seu toolbar precisa estar no mesmo XML que o seu reclycler view. Caso contrário ele se repete em cada item.